# Align between smiles symbol in box

Tags: align

My code can not edit to beautiful result.
Please help: align 4 smiles (vertical & horizontal)
Thanks 
[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2cm,right=2cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,scalerel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage[utf8]{english}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{MnSymbol,wasysym}
\usepackage{tikzsymbols} 
\usepackage[format=plain,
            labelfont={bf,it},
            textfont=it]{caption} 
%\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{pifont}
\input{insbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\makeatletter
\tcbset{
   myvbox/.style 2 args={%
        enhanced, 
        colback=white,
        colframe=blue!30!black,
        left=8mm,
        overlay={
            \node[rotate=90, anchor=north west, inner sep=2mm, text=white] (title@aux) at (frame.south west) {#2};
            \path[fill=tcbcol@frame] (title@aux.south west)--(title@aux.south east) 
                to[out=90, in=270] ([yshift=5mm]title@aux.east)--
                (title@aux.center|-frame.north)
                [rounded corners=\kvtcb@arc] -| 
                (frame.west) |- (title@aux.west)[sharp corners] -- cycle;   
            \node[rotate=90, inner sep=2mm, text=white] at (title@aux) {#2};
        },
        #1
  }
  }

\makeatother

\newtcolorbox{myvbox}[2][]{%
    myhbox={#1}{#2}
}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\noindent

\begin{tcbposter}
\posterbox[height=3cm,width =4.8cm, myvbox={colframe=blue!80!black}{Mood}]{column=1, row=2,  xshift=4.2cm, yshift=-1.3cm}{
 %\vspace*{0.2cm} 
  \\
 \hspace*{0.2cm} \dLaughey[2.0] \hspace*{0.5cm} \dNeutrey[2.0] \hspace*{0.5cm}  \\
\\

 \dInnocey[2.0]       \hspace*{0.5cm} \dWalley[2.0] \hspace*{0.5cm}
}

\end{tcbposter}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I removed all the packages that seemed unrelated to me. Consequently, the code runs through. As `tikzsymbols` works with saveboxes, it should be save to put these symbols in a tikz matrix. I hence placed such a matrix in a picture. There are a couple of parameters you may want to play with

- `at (1.4,-1)` determines the position of the matrix. If you increase `1.4`, the matrix will move right.
- `column sep=9pt` defines the distance between the columns.
- `row sep=3pt` sets the distance between the rows.
- `|[xshift=2mm]|` introduces an additional horizontal shift of the 22 entry.

These parameters should allow you to adjust the positions of the smileys, if needed. Notice that I did not mess around with the `posterbox` parameters. I do not know the source nor reason of these settings, but from your question I take that you'd like to keep them, and changing them is not necessary to place the smileys.

Here are the code and result.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2cm,right=2cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikzsymbols} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\makeatletter
\tcbset{
   myvbox/.style 2 args={%
        enhanced, 
        colback=white,
        colframe=blue!30!black,
        left=8mm,
        overlay={
            \node[rotate=90, anchor=north west, inner sep=2mm, text=white] (title@aux) at (frame.south west) {#2};
            \path[fill=tcbcol@frame] (title@aux.south west)--(title@aux.south east) 
                to[out=90, in=270] ([yshift=5mm]title@aux.east)--
                (title@aux.center|-frame.north)
                [rounded corners=\kvtcb@arc] -| 
                (frame.west) |- (title@aux.west)[sharp corners] -- cycle;   
            \node[rotate=90, inner sep=2mm, text=white] at (title@aux) {#2};
        },
        #1
  }
  }
\makeatother
\newtcolorbox{myvbox}[2][]{%
    myhbox={#1}{#2}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcbposter}
\posterbox[height=3cm,width =4.8cm, myvbox={colframe=blue!80!black}{Mood}]{%
column=1, row=2,  xshift=4.2cm, yshift=-1.3cm}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path(0,0);
\matrix[ampersand replacement=\&,matrix of nodes,column sep=9pt,
row sep=3pt] at (1.4,-1) {
 \dLaughey[2.0] \& \dNeutrey[2.0] \\
 \dInnocey[2.0] \& |[xshift=2mm]| \dWalley[2.0] \\
 };
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{tcbposter}
\end{document}
```

[image]